# UIImageView does not follow device orientation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a scrollView with several subViews. The subViews are defined like this:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
rect.size.height = screenRect.size.height;
rect.size.width = screenRect.size.width;
imageView.frame = screenRect;
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

This works fine until I change the interface orientation to landscape. The imageView is still in portrait mode, cutting the image in half. What should I do to change the portrait height and width, to landscape height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your code and check:

```
[imageView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

[imageView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Check this [link](http://userflex.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/autoresize-uiview-orientation/) too.

Comment: Probably you want to set `autoresizesSubviews = YES` to the parent view of `imageView` (`scrollView` in the above example) as well?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Rather than `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`, I use `self.view.bounds`. This (a) will factor out things like status bars, navigation bars, etc.; and (b) upon rotation, the width and height are automatically updated to reflect the new dimensions.
2. If you want your imageview to be resized for you, you generally set its `autoresizingMask` to something like `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`.
3. You might want to check your imageview's `contentMode` and set it to something like `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` so your whole image will always be displayed. That way, if you have a portrait image, it will always show up in portrait without distortion, without being cut off.
4. If you don't like the fact that your image view, itself, has been resized to landscape when you rotate the device, you can  reset its frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in iOS5 (in iOS4, use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for a UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

read more about that here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Once you detect the change, call the same code again.

Comment: In my personal experience, this is not needed unless you transition to new view controllers in such a way that your view controller hierarchy gets out of sync with the view hierarchy (e.g. some `[self.view addSubview:newController.view]` silliness). Generally you can just use the view controller's event methods for [responding to rotation events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW58).